# Can we parameterize Logical ID in AWS cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In my template the resource has the following structure,

```
"Resources" : {
      "myVPC" : {
         "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC",
         "Properties" : {
            "CidrBlock" : {"Ref" : "VpcCidr"},
            "EnableDnsSupport" : {"Ref" : "VpcEnableDnsSupport"},
            "EnableDnsHostnames" : {"Ref" : "VpcEnableDnsHostnames"},
            "InstanceTenancy" : {"Ref" : "VpcInstanceTenancy"},
            "Tags" : [ {"Key" : "Name", "Value" : {"Ref":"VpcName"}} ]
         }
      }
   }
```

Is there any way to parameterize **Logical ID** that is **"myVPC"** in this template.

Comment: I don't think so. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not in CloudFormation. But if you're using some kind of build process/server to build your templates before pushing them to an S3 bucket, you could do this using a simple sed command. I guess I'm confused as to why you would want to do this, though - I don't see any obvious utility?

Comment: Here's one: to get a fresh WaitConditionHandle when the stack is updated.

Comment: I have the exact same usecase is @Tavin where I want a fresh WaitConditionHandle on each deploy.